# SSH to debian server instantly logs out

Tags: shell, ssh, debian, plesk

I'm trying to help someone with their Debian server.

They have Plesk. I made myself an user with Plesk and enabled SSH access.

I *can* log on ... but only for one second. I see the MOTD, I see a Debian disclaimer, then I'm logged out again. "Connection closed".

The only thing I could think to try is to change the shell settings, Plesk has a dropdown list of bash, csh, tcsh and so on next to the "allow ssh using:" option. But none of them works.

Any ideas gratefully received.

Comment: What gets written to the logs on the Debian server?

Comment: What pam session modules are being used?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments and questions so far. I'm waiting for someone with admin access to get back to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plesk can get a bit quirky sometimes...

That behavior is similar to the one you get when a user account has a 'nologin' shell selected on the Plesk config. I would do some things:

- Connect using ssh with the verbose option activated (`ssh -v user@host`) so you can get more detail.
- Check the /etc/passwd file, look for your user and check that, the final field on that line, is pointing to a valid shell (something like `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/nologin` or `/bin/false`).
- Check also in that line that the home directory for that user ( that's configured on the field before of the shell ), is valid, exists, and has proper permissions and owner
- Finally, check your logs (in `/var/log`; I think I would check `syslog`, `messages` and `user`), so maybe you can get any meaningful message.

Comment: Indeed `/bin/false` in `/etc/passwd` is the most likely culprit. It's a silly practice, because, truly login should be blocked and MOTD not displayed, but some distros set that for "web only user".

Comment: The definition of "valid shell" is generally "a file mentioned in `/etc/shells`".

Answer (score 2):

The way I fixed this problem is, unfortunately, to manually change the last parameter in `/etc/passwd` for users I want to give shell access. It is `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/false`.

Comment: Manually?!  `chsh` is much less dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

When a user logs on, the shell takes them to their user directory and possibly runs a "startup" script.

1. Is the user directory on the local machine?  Does it have to be mounted from a fileshare (this has happened to me on more than one occasion)?  If that fileshare is not mounted you will get disconnected.
2. Take a look at the startup scripts for those shells.  Bash uses [various startup scripts depending on the circumstance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash#Startup_scripts), these include /etc/profile and ~/.bashrc.  These scripts sometimes do wacky things that may disconnect you for any number of reasons.